# FBX Export is not working (KeyError: ((nan, nan), 2)

Tags: export, error, .fbx

Hello everyone I got this error yesterday (Imgur Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIK8Q.png) and I spent the whole day trying to find a solution on the internet. Like you may think I ended up finding nothing.

Things that may help:

- I uninstalled Blender and reinstalled Blender on Steam after this error occured in belief this may help
- I want to export this as an FBX to export the map to Unity
- The few assets like the Desk, DeskLamp, Speaker, Monitor are from the Internet
- I don't care about materials (I just assigned a few to test out some things)
- I tried other files and they work fine

If you need more information just ask. I do anything to solve this problem.
Also please keep in mind I'm new in Blender thats why I don't know a lot of things.

If you want to try it yourself here is a link to my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s2akLn8_H_YpLr2XRFUPI7L4Kv5y9oJG?usp=sharing

Thanks to everyone who is trying to help me.

Comment: Try Blender from the official website [here](https://www.blender.org/)

Comment: I already tried to reinstall Blender and I tried both versions, but non of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use FBX format when you are able to avoid it. Its license makes it difficult to support in open source software so it is not supported well in Blender. Use alternatives like Collada, or [Alembic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)) instead when possible.

[image]