# Error when Exporting FBX

Tags: export, error, .fbx

I have a model I got commissioned, and I would like to get it as an FBX, but, after I hit save on the file explorer, I get a whole ton of lines, which, at the end, say “key error ((nan, nan) 360)[image]” I've tried multiple versions of Blender, and alsways get the same result.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216032/fbx-export-is-not-working-keyerror-nan-nan-2

Comment: @JohnEason I realize it's a horrible format, but in order to get it to unity, i have to have it in that format

Comment: There was a very long thread about it on https://developer.blender.org/ around 3 years ago [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/79775) and it was thought to have been fixed then, but seems to have surfaced again since then. It's not really something we can advise on here

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the follow up.